# Getting Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: reactjs, console

I am working on a project and using appwrite database for the backend. I am getting the documents array from my collection and storing in postItems array locally.
This is code for getting the list of documents.I have defined getData() in a file appwrite.js and I am exporting it.

```
  getData: async () => {
    let promise = appwrite.database.listDocuments('61713e3e5257a');
    promise.then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.documents) //response.documents is a array
        return response.documents
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error); // Failure
    });
},
```

Then is another file dashboard.js I have imported that and I am calling this to set data using useEffect like this.

```
const [postItems, setPostItems] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const getPostData = async () => {
        try {
        
                const data = await api.getData()
                data.map((doc) => {
                    setPostItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, {
                        location: doc.location,
                        date: doc.date,
                        text: doc.experience
                    }])
                })

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    }
    getPostData()
    console.log(postItems)
}, [])
```

I am not able to retrive data and getting console error as "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"
I am not able to understand what is wrong,as the getData() function is returning response.documents which is a array and I was using that to setPostItems. Would be really helpful if anyone can point out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue source is `getData` function. You have forgotten to return the data from the function.
Add `return promise`

Comment: Ya, thanks for pointing that out, I also had to return the promise. This solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to return resolve see below answer

```
getData: async () => {
    let promise = appwrite.database.listDocuments('61713e3e5257a');
    promise.then(function (response) {
        resolve(response.documents);
        console.log(response.documents) //response.documents is a array
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error); // Failure
    });
},
```

Comment: I tried this, I am getting error as resolve is not a function.

Comment: What is `resolve` in your code? It is not defined  :/

Comment: No need to defined that function it's global see this ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

Comment: `resolve` in your link is a static method of `Promise`